# Why some java methods in core libraries end with numbers?

Tags: naming-conventions, java

It's common in a lot of classes in JDK, just a few examples:

1. [java.util.Properties](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Properties.java)

   - load0
   - store0
2. [java.lang.Thread](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java)

   - start0
   - stop0
   - setPriority0

Usually they are private native methods (like in Thread class), but sometimes they are just private (Properties class)

I'm just curious if anybody know if there is any history behind that.

Comment: Where is Joshua Bloch? Maybe it used to be Sun's coding standard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The use of zero suffixes on method names is just a convention to deal with cases where you have a public API method and a corresponding private method.  In the Java SE libraries, this is commonly used for  the `native` methods that provide the underlying functionality implemented by the classes.  (You can see what is going on by looking at the OpenJDK source code.)

But your questions are:

> Why some java methods in core libraries end with numbers?

Because someone thought it would be a good idea.  It is not strictly necessary since they *typically* could have overloaded the public methods instead.  And since the zero suffix matters are private, the naming of methods should not be relevant beyond the class and its native implementation.

> I'm just curious if anybody know if there is any history behind that.

There is no mention of this convention in the original Java Style Guide.  In fact, I think it predates Java.  I vaguely recall seeing it in C libraries in 4.x BSD Unix.  That was the mid 1980's.  And I wouldn't be surprised if they adopted it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 15):

I believe they are named like that because equivalent functions with same names exist in the code and just to distinguish between native helper functions and public functions they decided to suffix them with 0.

in `java.util.Properties` both `load`, `store` and `load0`, `store0` exist.

Comment: The source (jre6) shows that the `store` and `load` functions call the `load0` and `store0` after wrapping the parameters.

Answer (score 9):

The 0 after the method name is done so to distinguish between **public** and **private** methods having same name .

`Start` function will call the `start0` function.
Those functions which ends with 0 is private method. 
And those which are not ending with number is public.
You can check in any of the library.